# Mapbox: how can i disable two finger 3d tilt on touch devices

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Mapbox: cannot disable 3D tilt on touch devices

I have tried to disable the tilt with the following functions without success:

`map.current.dragPan.disable(); map.current.dragRotate.disable(); map.current.touchZoomRotate.disable();`

Comment: You need to disable the pitch handler https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/handlers/#touchpitchhandler

It is undocumented., but it should inherit functions from `TwoTouchHandler` as seen in the source code https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/198bb84eb9e6dba719e66ab06e9c312ab8596d7b/src/ui/handler/touch_zoom_rotate.js#L210-L287

`TwoTouchHandler` has the function `disable()` which could possible solve your problem if you have added a pitchHandler somewhere in the code.

Comment: You can also use https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#setmaxpitch to set pitch to 90 and always stay at "top-down" view

Answer (score 2):

I used this to fix the pitch to top-down, thereby disabling any gestures.

```
map.setMaxPitch(0);
map.setMinPitch(0);
```

Second version (see https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#touchpitch):

```
// disable map tilting using two-finger gesture
map.touchPitch.disable();
```

Two of the things you tried actually disable rotating the map in the sense that north isn't "up" any more.

```
// disable map rotation using right click + drag
map.dragRotate.disable();

// disable map rotation using touch rotation gesture
map.touchZoomRotate.disableRotation();
```

Also explained here:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/disable-rotation/